# Get a process executable path from it's PID (or using tasklist)

Tags: java, windows, pid

I want to get a certain process path using it's PID
For example, I have `Discord.exe  1300  Console  1  32.364 Ko` from tasklist.exe, and I want to transform `1300` to `C:/Users/Me/AppData/Local/Discord/app/Discord.exe`

Anyone knows how I can manage to do that, or an alternative way to get all the process informations

Also I use java for all of that

Comment: *NtQuerySystemInformation(SystemProcessIdInformationSystemProcessIdInformation,..*

Comment: Why aren't you using [ProcessHandle](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessHandle.html)